# send-email option from activity history; How to populate contacts list view on custom object record?

Tags: email, tasks, activities, send-email

How could I populate the contacts list view for a custom object record when I click the CC link on send-email page from a activity history related list? I am able to see that list view on Accounts but not for any other custom object. Why? I have a look up on my custom object to contact. Also can I populate a contact list view on master object which brings the contacts related to its child object?

**For my custom object:**

[image]

**But for Accounts I have**

[image]

Comment: Done with a custom button logic using Email URL hack.